# AWS SSL cert for server api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I use netlify.com for the front-end (React.js) which automatically comes with https, but it's not allowing me to make https requests to the express server as my express server does not have a cert.

How do I get a cert for my express server (**which serves only RESTFUL APIs**) with AWS Certificate Manager? It's asking for domain name but all I have is a static IP for the AWS EC2 instance.

If AWS Certificate Manager is not suitable for this case, what's the easiest free way to get a cert and set it up for the Express server? I'm running the Express server directly via node, without apache/nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to point a domain name to the REST API server. You can't request an SSL certificate for an IP address. Do you not own a domain name that is pointing to your React app already? You should setup a subdomain like api.example.com that points to your API server, and then request an Amazon SSL certificate for that subdomain.

Note, you must be using an Elastic Load Balancer or CloudFront to use an Amazon Certificate Manager SSL certificate. You can't install it directly on an EC2 instance.

Comment: netlify.com provides a subdomain for you (eg. my-website.netlify.com), so I don't have one. So I'd have to purchase a custom domain name?

Comment: Yes, you can't request an SSL certificate for an IP address, and you can't request an SSL certificate for a domain you don't personally own.

Comment: I've gotten a custom domain and added my AWS ec2 IP address as its name server. What else do I have to do to access my API at the custom domain?

Comment: Your EC2 server is not a DNS name server. Your EC2 instance is a web/API server. Where did you purchase the domain from? Wherever you purchased it probably offers DNS hosting service. You would create an `A` record in your DNS settings that points to the EC2 server's IP address. That will allow the domain to work. However, like I said above, if you are pointing directly at the EC2 server instead of either a load balancer or CloudFront, then you can't use the free Amazon SSL certificates.

Comment: The load balancer's DNS name looks like `balancer-for-https-123456.ap-region-1.elb.amazonaws.com`, which is not a valid ip address. How would I create an `A record` that points to the load balancer? I'm using namecheap

Comment: Who is yor DNS host?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158284/discussion-between-avery235-and-mark-b).